# Assembly DB directive and integer value

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm trying to code a simple hello word in Assembly.
The data section contains:

```
section .data
message: db 'hello, world!', 10
```

However i have 2 doubts about it:

1) Is the 10 integer stored using 2 bytes ? Moreover is the 10 integer stored using the ASCII representation ?

2) Does this 10 represent the "\n" we find in C language ?

Comment: `10` is a single byte for the newline char in decimal---same as `\n` in c.

Comment: you can also use `-l` listing option for nasm to see resulting machine code interleaved by source, there is the single byte with value 10 visible too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It is a single byte.
2. Yes, it's the same thing as c-style `\n`.

Additionally, you can use backquotes to use c-style strings in NASM:

```
message: db 'hello, world!', 10
message: db 'hello, world!', 0x0A
message: db `hello, world!\n`
```

These are all the same. See [DB and Friends](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.13.03/html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.2.1) and [Character Strings](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.13.03/html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.4.2).

Note that the last version uses backticks instead of single quotes.  Inside single quotes `db '\n'` is the same as `db 92, 110` (the ASCII codes for backslash and lower-case n.)  http://asciitable.com/